Playwright timeout
I am very new to playwright and I am trying a simple POC where I open a URL, enter user and password and click LOGIN button. Then checking if a particular title is present or not.
This is my simple code.
import pytest
import asyncio
from playwright.sync_api import Page, expect, async_playwright

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_has_title():
  async with async_playwright() as p:
     browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
     page = await browser.new_page()
     agree_button = "//button[@class='agree-btn'][contains(text(),'AGREE & CONTINUE')]"
     user_text_box = "USER"
     pwd_text_box = "PASSWORD"
     login_button = "//button[contains(text(),'LOGIN')]"
     await page.goto("https://my-url.com")

     await page.get_by_role("button", name="AGREE & CONTINUE").click()
     await page.get_by_placeholder("Username").click()
     await page.get_by_placeholder("Username").fill("myuser")
     await page.get_by_placeholder("Password").click()
     await page.get_by_placeholder("Password").fill("mypassword")
     await page.get_by_role("button", name="LOGIN",).click()
     await expect(page.locator('title')).to_have_text('Welcome', timeout=50000)

I run this using this command from Pycharm.
pytest -v -s --capture=tee-sys --html=report.html .\test_login.py --headed

This is running ok until it encounters the await expect page and throws this error.
await expect(page.locator('title')).to_have_text('Citco Treasury', timeout=50000)
..\venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\__init__.py:142: in __call__
raise ValueError(f"Unsupported type: {type(actual)}")
E   ValueError: Unsupported type: <class 'playwright.async_api._generated.Locator'>

This app after clicking the LOGIN button will take few seconds to load so that the title is
visible. Is that a reason for this error? Its unable to find the title just after clicking LOGIN button?
Any help is much appreciated.
By the way await is supposed to wait until the next action in the test sequence?

Did you try letting Playwright launch the browser and create the page for you? Like in here https://playwright.dev/python/docs/writing-tests#first-test

Thank you. That seems to have worked. But many of my tests are dependent on each other, so I thought I'll use await (async api). My understanding is using await will automatically wait for required web element to be visible, but I may be wrong. When exactly should I use async with await?

My guess is that for expect to work with locators it needs to use elements coming from the instance playwright created.

I don't want to sound rude. Take it as a piece of advice. Your tests shouldn't depend on each other. Your tests will be hard to maintain and scale.

I agree. But the application I am trying to automate is designed in such a way that I cannot proceed to a particular step without the previous step is successful. For eg: I must create a payment first before I can move it to a "Confirmed" status. So if I want to test the Confirm functionality, I must first have the payment created successfully. Similarly there are various stages of the payment (like Sign1, Sign2 etc), but for all of these paymentId remains same.

@Ram that means your tests need to call the same functions, not run one after another. Put the steps/common functionality in separate functions or even page object models and then call the steps from your tests

In fact, it's one of Playwright's most important features that each test can run concurrently on a separate browser or tab. What you try to do isn't just bad test practice, it works against the tool you're using

@Ram all applications require specific steps in a scenario. QA testers don't chain tests to build one scenario, they create different tests per scenario, performing the steps needed in that scenario. Using a page object model (ie one class per page with its locators and even actions specified as fields/properties) makes the tests less fragile to app changes. An even better option is to use Scenario or even User classes that abstract the actual steps or actions that call the page models.

The Selenium docs call abstracting the steps creating a Domain Specific Language. Notice how creating a loginUser method that abstracts the login step makes testing multiple scenarios a lot easier
